# How much did the Highschool DxD anime adapt the light novel?

Tags: high-school-dxd

I finished watching season 3 of Highschool DxD and I want to read the LN. I don't know where to start reading. How much did the Highschool DxD anime adapt the light novel, and did the anime adapt the LN well?

Comment: At least we can be sure that both didn't *cover* boobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Season 1: Volumes 1 and 2

Season 2: Volumes 3 and 4

Season 3 episodes 1-9: Volumes 5,6 and 7

Season 3 episodes 10-12: Original

Ovas and Specials: Half of volume 8 and original

The most likely future:

Season 4: Volumes 9 and 10. The way these 2 volumes work it should be this way

I watched the anime and read the light novels.

About your second question yes, it was very well adapted. Season 3 was a mess though so I'd advise you to read it. Just for Koneko it's worth it. It's nice having her fall for Issei and enter mating season. Koneko in the heat is the best Koneko :)

Answer (score 1):

Anime covered about 7 first volumes.

Based on [Manga-Updates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=72062)