# Highschool DxD Anime to Manga

Tags: high-school-dxd

Where does season 4 of High School DxD start in the reading? I watched seasons 1-3 of the anime, High School DxD. If the light novel has more story or less story in it please let me know.

Comment: Just so you know even if there's manga adaption. High School DxD is based on light novel, not manga. So if you want to know how far the original source read the light novel

Comment: from my understanding the 4th season is planned to air in japan in 2018. also *Highschool DxD* is a light novel series with Manga and Anime Adaptations, both the Light Novel and Main Manga are on-going so both would have more content than the current anime

Comment: The light novel part is already answered in this question https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/38302/2869

Comment: the anime drifted away from the light novel. I'm curious to see how they manage to bring it back